# Help making this cool guitar sort of lead

Tags: sound-design, synthesis

Im trying to make this cool guitar sort of lead (I use Massive btw).  I got a pretty cool sound doing the following:

Three saw wave oscillators  The first two detuned by three cents and a third an octave lower in which I also turn down the amp on somewhat.  All going to two filters.

Filter 1 is a daft filter starting at slightly less than 12 o clock
Filter 2 is a lowpass 4 filter starting at 12 oclock 
both filters have very smmall amount of resonance on it

[image]

Filters 1 and 2 have 1 envolope controlling modulation of about almost all the way with both resonances being raised as well.   This envelope looks like the follwing

[image]

Amp envelope is the following:

[image]

Ive added some tube distortiona with a dimension expander to give it some more width and power.  A bit of bitcrusher as well.  Im getting a cool sound but I wanted something more of the sound seen here starting at 1:47

However I cant seem to get that cool wah effect.  Its a great lead, would help me out alot in my education of sound design.

Comment: Sounds like only one 24 dB per octave filter with the resonance up maybe halfway. Then the filter envelope has a fast attack and a longer decay and either the envelope is not retriggered on legato notes or there's an LFO on the filter frequency or maybe a controller like the mod wheel is opening and closing the filter.

Comment: yea thats whatll give you the wah.  Seems like its going in the right direction.  Ill play around with it see what I can get.  I think you can just use a velocity to contoll the amount of envelope.